# Object creation across multiple files (Java)

Tags: java, object

so I have 2 files called Employee.java and Write.java (These two are within the same package). Say within Employee.java I have

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName = "test";
    private String lastName = "ing";

    public Employee(String first, String last) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }

    public Employee(Employee copy) {
        firstName = copy.firstName;
        lastName = copy.lastName;
    }
}
```

Then within my Write.java I want to create an object of type Employee called temp. Like

```
public void obtainInfo(Employee temp) {
    String firstName = temp.firstName;
    String lastName = temp.lastName;
}
```

However I get an error that tells me that it cannot find the symbol in the line that is.

```
public void obtainInfo(Employee temp) {
```

I was just wondering where I went wrong that I can't create an object within different files. Despite them being in the same package I can't access them?

I want to be able to incorporate this later on to help me build a text file from reading an array list, but I figured to first start with reading a single line from an object.

Comment: Please post all of Write.java so we can see where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you are trying to set something up so that you can make a copy of an Employee and be able to write the properties to a text file. This won't write to a text file but I think it may clear some things up for you.

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Employee(Employee copy) {
        firstName = copy.firstName;
        lastName = copy.lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Employee");
        sb.append("{firstName='").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", lastName='").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //First we have to have one to copy
        Employee emp = new Employee("Joe", "Dirt");

        //Now we have a copy
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(emp);

        //Calls the Employee.toString() method and sends it to System.out
        System.out.println("Employee 1 : " + emp);
        System.out.println("Copy of Employee 1 : " + emp2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Write.java's class has the same level of access as Employee (IE: Public).  If this is not the issue, I would show the code from Write.java specifically as that is most likely where the problem is coming from.